# grid.getColumnmanager().getColumns() is not giving parent column in Ext JS grid

Tags: grid, extjs4.2

I have grid having grouped columns.

**Some of my code is as follows:**

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.grid.*',
'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel'
...
]);

var filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: false,
    local: true  
};

var grid = new Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    store: store,
    columns:[
    {
        header: "Column1"
        dataIndex: 'Column1'
    },{
        header: "Column2",
        columns : [{
            header: "innerColumn1",
            dataIndex: 'innerColumn1'
        },{
            header: "innerColumn2"
            dataIndex: 'innerColumn2'
    }]
    },{
        header: "Column3",
        dataIndex: 'Column3'
    }],
    features: [filters]
 ...
```

Now, if I use `grid.columnManager.getColumns()` it returns following columns:

```
Column1
innerColumn1
innerColumn2 
Column3
```

It is not returning `Column2` which is a parentColumn/groupColumn of `innerColumn1` & `innerColumn2`.  Which method of Ext Js I should use to get `Column2` as well in the columnList? I am using Ext Js 4.2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could traverse the columns, but the point of the column manager is to deal with leaf columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid.getColumnmanager().getColumns()` does not provide parent column of grouped columns. Column manager is to deal with only leaf columns.

While iterating columns you can access `isSubHeader` property only available in child groped columns and after that through `ownerCt` property you can access parent column.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution to get all the columns is to make use of Ext ComponentQuery. I have created this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/186d). Look into the developer console of after running this fiddle.

So simplest query to get all the columns is :

```
grid.query('gridcolumn:not([hidden])')// Open fiddle for full example
```

It will simply return all visible columns. You can change query according to your requirements.

For Example, to get only the Grouped Column, you can use this

```
grid.query('gridcolumn[isGroupHeader=true]')
```

[Click here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) for more information about ComponentQuery.